# SQL Server query get rows table 1 - rows table 2 without null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

```
select 
    id, amount - (select sum(amount) as amount 
                  from table2 
                  where column = 'value' and table1.id = table2.id 
                  group by table2.id) as amount
from 
    table1 
order by 
    table1.id
```

The result is all values from table1 - `amount` from `table2` except the `table1.id`'s that are not in `table2.id`'s they get null value.

So it's all good except that I have the null values because I need these to be the `table1.amount` value

Also tried stuff like this but still not working

```
select 
     id, amount - isnull((select sum(amount) as amount 
                          from table2 
                          where column = 'value' and table1.id = table2.id 
                          group by table2.id), table1.amount) as amount
from 
     table1 
order by 
     table1.id
```

Then I get `0.00` but the `table1.id`'s that have null in result set do have a real amount value in `table1.amount`

Overview of what I need

```
table 1   values    (1,12 ; 2,27 ; 3,9) table 2   values    (1,9 ; 3,12) result table (1,3 ; 2,27 ; 3,-3)
```

so I need table1 - values from table 2 to get result table

Comment: It's *amount* (with a single `m` - not *ammount*) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better do this

```
select
t1.id, t1.amount - isnull(t2.amountTable2,0) as 'amount'
from table1 T1
left join (select id, sum(ammunt) as 'amountTable2' from table2 group by Id) T2
       on t1.id = t2.id
order by t1.id
```

this will get the total `Sum` of each id in `table2`
then will `join` by id, and do the difference.
If there is no id in `table2`, will use 0

That answer consider (I thougth that at first) that t2.Id could be repeated
If it's unique, remove the group by

```
select
    t1.id, t1.amount - isnull(t2.amount,0) as 'Totalamount'
    from table1 T1
    left join table2 T2
           on t1.id = t2.id
    order by t1.id
```